# Is the order of Ruby Dir.entries guaranteed?

Tags: ruby

What is the order of the entries returned by `Dir.entries`? How do you know if it is fixed or can change at any time?

The [Ruby Doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Dir.html#method-c-entries) doesn't seem to say.